# Accordian menu - how to keep first div open by default

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$(".content").hide();

    $('.button').click(function() 
        {
            $('.content').slideUp('normal');
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
            $(".button1").removeClass().addClass("button");
            $(this).removeClass().addClass("button1");
        });

});

</script>
<style>
li { list-style:none;}
.button { width: 800px; float: left; background:green; color:#fff; cursor: pointer;}
.button1 {  width: 800px; float: left; background:blue; color:#fff; cursor: pointer;}
.content {  width: 800px; float: left; background: #95B1CE; display: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li class="button">accordian button</li>
  <li class="content">Content 1</li>
  <li class="button">accordian button</li>
  <li class="content">Content 2</li>
  <li class="button">accordian button</li>
  <li class="content">Content 3</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe some more explanation would help, instead of just a bunch of code..

Comment: I want "Content 1" open by default, rest will work as it is

Answer (score 2):

You should use ids to reference your elements. Also I don't think your html structure is the best one.

I personally recommend using something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="selected" id="button1">
    <div class="button">accordion button</div>
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>
  </li>
  <li id="button2">
    <div class="button">accordion button</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  </li>
  <liid="button3">
    <div class="button">accordion button</div>
    <div class="content">Content 3</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now that the first one is selected by default, use css.

```
.content {
  display: none;
}

.selected .content {
  display: block;
}
```

The script should also change:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
  var selected = $(".selected");
  selected.children(".content").slideUp();
  selected.removeClass("selected");
  var button = $(this);
  button.next().slideDown();
  button.parent().addClass("selected"); // optional
});
```

Not tested but I think it's understandable.

Comment: Really? Replacing an answer with an entirely different one counts as an edit? Oh, I get it - because the question is closed and adding other answers is disabled. Whatever the cause, I cannot approve this, because the original post is replaced completely and I am listed as the author of something I didn't write. I am rolling it back.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$(".content:eq(0)").show();` after `$(".content").hide();`

Actually `$(".content").hide();` is not required. Your are making display:none in css

it will work [jsfilddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KHsE/2/)

find below full Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//$(".content").hide();
$(".content:eq(0)").show();
$('.button:eq(0)').addClass('button1');

$('.button').click(function() 
    {
        $('.content').slideUp('normal');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        $(".button").removeClass("button1");
        $(this).addClass("button1");
    });
```

});

Comment: The only problem in this solution is that the element is theoretically invisible between the calls to hide() and show().

Comment: but I will need link class(default is button and selected is button1) also as selected. If I am showing first div open then its parent also should show selected class. Could you please guide me how to do that.